# Spring boot swagger :custom information about Api not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am trying to add custom information about the API. I added custom information but its not working. I am getting old information. can any one please tell me why I am not getting custom information? `http://localhost:8086/swagger-ui.html`
Here I added my dependency and swagger configuration file

**Dependency**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
package com.spacestudy.config;

import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(metaData())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.spacestudy.controller"))
                .paths(regex("/api.spacestudy.com"))
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo metaData() {

        Contact contact = new Contact("XYZ", "XYZ.com", XYZ@gmail.com);
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()

        .title("Spring Boot REST API")
        .description("Spring Boot REST API for Space Study")
        .version("1.0.0")
        .license("Apache 2.0")
        .contact(contact)
        .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0")       
        .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: why its not working on my side. you changed any thing

Comment: Here is my Docket Bean https://pastebin.com/YVZDTfrQ. I have same version of springfox as well

Comment: in the above code I forgot to add ` @Bean`  when i added this annotation i got custom information but now not showing end points

Comment: I got ans.  in path need to add `* `  `paths(regex("/api.spacestudy.com.*"))`

Comment: thank you so much for your reply